# Can I serve a static html page from mvc

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, single-page-application

I would like to be abel to run my angularjs app from the app directory from VS code without using VS2015 and without running iis express. This will make it possible to create new UI very fast specially combined with mocking the service layer.

It's a mvc5 + webapi2 application.

So I need to run /app/index.html from mvc. The index.html is a full html page not an angular template.

Comment: Try `Server.MapPath("~");` and make index.html available at this path.

Answer (score 3):

Create an action method that returns perticular HTML file. You can return File from controller action. have a look:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var result = new FilePathResult("~/Html/index.htm", "text/html");
    return result;
}
```

Also check this Class: [FileResult](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/system.web.mvc.fileresult(v=vs.100).aspx)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

You can simply call:
   return Redirect("~/path/to/.html");

Answer (score 1):

2 ways of doing so:

i. Simple replace the original index.html to your new index.html, all other libraries please place in side the corresponding folder.

ii. in web.config, you may change the maproute properties, you can map your view as default or add new map route.

Thank you.